# React export declaration statement expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to export my component my editor show me an error `export declaration statement expected`

here is my code:

```
export Header from './Header/Header';
```

but if I do this:

```
export {default as Header} from './Header/Header';
```

it doesn't show any error.

my Header.js

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  //code
}
```

I'm following this example https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/index.js

My component folder structure and export method same like those link.

Any solution?

Comment: `export {default as Header} from './Header/Header';` looks right to me. What's the issue with that?

Comment: @Felix Kling no issues. I'm curious why at the link I post, there's no issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any solution?

`export Header from './Header/Header';` is not valid syntax, however there exists a [proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from) to support it.

The repository you linked to [configured babel](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/.babelrc) to support this proposed feature by using the [`stage-0`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) preset:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  ...
}
```

`stage-0` includes [`stage-1`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/) which contains the [`transform-export-extensions` plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/) that implements this feature.

---

But to be clear, you don't *have* to use this experimental feature.

```
export {default as Header} from './Header/Header';
```

has the same effect and is standard ES6.

Comment: Hi, good catch!. I'm using vscode and set the .babelrc to using stage-0 why is it still shown error (package already installed)?

Comment: I don't know how vscode works, it might not be aware of babel. I wouldn't expect IDEs to support every experimental feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`export default from './Header/Header';`

Comment: I cant do this. I need to call this file globally.

Comment: This form is not officially supported, it only exists as [*proposal*](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from). If you are suggesting to use experimental features, then please also explain what to do in order to use them.

Comment: I see. I am not sure what editor you use but your `export Header from './Header/Header';` works for me. I use WebStorm.